# & returns incorrect pid when used with docker exec

Tags: bash, docker, command-line-interface, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am currently trying to spawn and kill hyperledger composer rest server instances using the `nohup` command.

In order to spawn new hyperledger composer rest server instances, I need to execute such commands in the docker cli container.
This is how I do it for now:

```
# start an interactive terminal with cli container
docker exec -it cli bash

# start rest server with defined port number
nohup composer-rest-server -c <myCard> -p <myPort> &
```

This will return me a pid that relates to the process id of the rest server.

However, if I do it this way,

```
# run a process that is detached to start the rest server
docker exec -d cli composer-rest-server -c <myCard> -p <myPort> &
```

The rest server will be started, however, the pid that is returned is **not** the pid of the rest server.

Why is this happening?

PS: I need the pid to kill the spawned rest server later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second command, the ending `&` works on `docker exec` itself, not on the process running inside the container.

Since you have run the container in detached mode with the `-d` option, why bother putting the rest server in background?

Comment: Hi, so are you saying that I should remove the -d flag and replace it with `nohup` instead?

Comment: No, you should keep the `-d` flag and remove the ending `&`, as this: `docker exec -d cli composer-rest-server -c <myCard> -p <myPort>`

Comment: If not, is it possible to add the `&` to be part of the command to run in the `docker exec`?

Comment: Oh, I need to get the pid for that rest server process. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: To get the pid: `docker exec cli pidof composer-rest-server`

Comment: does this `pidof` works if I have to start multiple rest server instance but at different ports?

Comment: Yes, it will show all the pids, seperated by space. Or you can `docker exec cli ps -ef` to show all running processes.